# How to get Cobertura and Ivy working together?

Tags: ant, ivy, cobertura

I was just starting to integrate [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) into our main product's build process which uses [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) as the dependency management tool. There are several libraries `lib-a`, `lib-b` and `lib-c` that do not have test cases and one project that depends on these libs and contains the unit and integration tests for all of these libraries.

Generally, instrumenting, running the instrumented tests and generating the Cobertura report works. However, there are several problems:

- During instrumentation, there are several warnings (about 10) reported:

  `Problems instrumenting archive entry: a.b.c.MyClassFoo java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.b.c.MyClassBar`

  However, the reported class is exisiting. At the end of instrumentation, it reports

  `Saved information on 364 classes`
- When viewing the report, it shows all classes, but all classes of dependent libs are reported as 0% coverage.
- When viewing details, it reports that no sources where found.

Now I think the problem might be, that Cobertura has problems with 
- instrumenting the class files provided as jar files and
- Getting the sources from jar files

The instrumentation ant task in my build.xml does the following:

```
    <cobertura-instrument todir="${build.dir}/instrumented-classes">
        <includeClasses regex="com\.mycompany.*" />
        <instrumentationClasspath>
            <path refid="default.test.classpath" />
            <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}" />
        </instrumentationClasspath>     
    </cobertura-instrument>
```

Should this be sufficient?

Im wondering, because of the reported warnings. All reported classes can be found within the jars.

For the second problem, I don't even know how to provide sources as jars to cobertura-report...

I tried

```
<cobertura-report destdir="${build.dir}/coverage">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.java" />
    </fileset>
    <ivy:cachefileset conf="runtime-test" type="sources"/>
</cobertura-report>
```

but it says `cachefileset` is not supported. I also tried using a `pathid` which I also can't provide in `cobertura-report`.
Do I have to unzip all sources before (which would be very time-consuming) and then provide them as a normal `fileset`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, while refactoring my Cobertura Ant tasks, I was able to solve the problem with dependency classes reported as 0% coverage.

At first my test task contained the following:

```
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${build.test.classes.dir}"/>
            <pathelement path="${build.dir}/instrumented-classes"/>         
            <pathelement path="${build.classes.dir}"/>
            <path refid="default.test.classpath"/>
            <path refid="cobertura.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        (...)
    </junit>
```

The problem was, that instrumenting the jar files provided by ivy results in jar files within the `${build.dir}/instrumented-classes` directory. However, `pathelement` supposedly only looks for class files. So I added a `fileset` to include the instrumented jars as well:

```
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${build.test.classes.dir}"/>
            <pathelement path="${build.dir}/instrumented-classes"/>
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}/instrumented-classes">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>              
            <pathelement path="${build.classes.dir}"/>
            <path refid="default.test.classpath"/>
            <path refid="cobertura.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        (...)
    </junit>
```

The other problems still remain.